# A group is abelian if and only if $\varphi(x) = x^{-1}$ is an automorphism.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that given $G$ a group, $\varphi: G \to G $ given by $\varphi(x) = x^{-1}$ is an automorphism if and only if $G$ is abelian.

I've already shown that $\varphi$ is bijective, irrespective of whether $G$ is abelian, so the only additional distinguishing factor of an automorphism is the homomorphism property. I believe I've found a way to prove this in a way where the steps are reversible. My attempt is:

> Suppose $\varphi$ is an automorphism. Then $\varphi(xy) = \varphi(x) \varphi(y)$ for all $x,y \in G$, so $(xy)^{-1} = x^{-1} y^{-1} = (yx)^{-1}$. By uniqueness of inverses, this implies that $xy = yx$, so $G$ is abelian. All of these steps are reversible. If $G$ is abelian, given $x,y \in G$, $xy = yx$. Then $(xy)^{-1} = (yx)^{-1}$, but $(yx)^{-1} = x^{-1} y^{-1} = \varphi(x) \varphi(y)$, so $\varphi(xy) = \varphi(x) \varphi(y)$, and $\varphi$ is an automorphism.

Have I made a mistake?

Comment: No, you are good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. It's good :) :) :)